# start UITextView Text from bottom right corner like it works on calculator

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to make a calculator app in which I want to start text to start displaying from bottom right corner of UITextView.

Comment: why you do not use Text Field instead of Text View

Answer (score 2):

Just do that:

```
textView.textAlignment = .right
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below line for your textView

```
self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.textView.frame.size.height - 5, 0, 0, 0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Instead of static value 80 use this line `self.textView.frame.size.height - 5` and by the way it is `UITextView` not `UITextField` @Dev_Tandel

Comment: @UITextField whatever